# How to install TPX drawing tool

Tags: diagrams

I have downloaded TPX Drawing tool to make some drawing for latex document but it has many files inside the zip file, nothing is there to install. I am in windows. I downloaded it from

[TPX Drawing Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpx/).

How could I install it?

[image: screenshot of tpx folder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download *TpX_ExecDistribution1_5.zip* from http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpx/files/tpx/TpX%201.5/ instead, in that zip file there is a `TpX.exe` that you can run. If I remember correctly you don't actually have to install, just double-click the `.exe`

Comment: There is no `.exe` file

Comment: @wafeeq Eh, yes there is. Inside the zip file called TpX_ExecDistribution1_5.zip.

Comment: i have edit my question with screenshot

Comment: @wafeeq *Wrong zip file*. That screenshot is from TpX_Source1_5.zip.

Comment: got it. Thanks. One more thing. Actually I want to import a pdf fine in latex to edit but the problem is that when I opend pdf file in tpx it says `psToEdit` file not created. I have already asked this question but no body answered

Comment: @wafeeq No idea, I don't use TpX. Why not just add comments in Matlab?